# socket.io not sending message to server

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a web application using socket.io, I want to be able to send message to my server which is on my VPS but it shows no error, and it's not sending the message, the clients are mot receiving it even in the server, I try to `console.log` the error message but it's not getting any message

Here is the code for the server:

```
var app = require('express')();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(`******`),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(`******`)
}
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('host', process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0');

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.json({ message: "Welcome to My application." }));

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('chat message', msg => {
        console.log(msg)
        io.emit('chat message', msg)
    });
});
server.listen(app.get('port'), app.get('host'), () => console.log("Express server listening IP: " + app.get('host')));
```

Here is the code for the client side which is on my laptop

```
<form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.3/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha512-uElffqRAo44n9cqo42itgRMY0L0zNZWEj3RGTQwyQsITiz4CB6rALOu1/S4O5iy/vFTMNs8gmTpDXB8mfQpjOg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var socket = io.connect('https://****:3000', {
                secure: true,
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            })
            $('form').submit(function() {
                socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
            });
            socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
                console.log(msg)
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Please what am I doing that is wrong and how can I solve this issue?